# Why can't I paste the child pane plist file into a project's Settings.bundle folder in Xcode 4.3.3?

Tags: ios, sdk, xcode4.3

I'm running Xcode 4.3.3 and I've been following a tutorial about app settings. Everything has been going great up until I get ready to add a plist for a child pane that I want to add.

I tried the suggestion in a very similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6978203/1543207) and I'm following the same tutorial as specified within the linked post.

1. Open up finder, you can right click or two finger click Settings.bundle and choose "Show in Finder".
2. Right click Settings.bundle in the finder window, choose show package contents.
3. Copy the new plist file into this the settings.bundle next to the Root.plist
4. Delete the new plist from the main project.

I can copy the plist file but I can't paste the plist file created into settings.bundle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.In Xcode 4.3.2,

1. Right click the Project Name in the Project Navigator, and choose `Show in Finder`;
2. In Finder, right click the setting.bundle and choose `Show Package Contents`;
3. Copy the new .plist to setting.bundle;
4. Back to XCode, open the `setting.bundle`, wilfully add one item under the `Preference Items`, then expand it and modify the value of `Type` to `Child Pane`.I can't upload the image, so give the [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/submarine/archive/2012/07/25/2607854.html) of the blog.

I hope can help you.