# Adding a second .plist as Child Pane

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, settings.bundle, root.plist

I have a lot of troubles adding into my Root.plist a Child Pane.
I've seen the same question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978203), but I can't solve it with those answers.
Sorry for repeat similar questions.

This is a capture of Root.plist:
[image: Root.plist]

And here is a capture of Connection.plist:
[image: Connection.plist]

What I do, step by step is:

1.- Create a new Property List named "Connection.plist"

2.- As the new property list is out of my Settings.bundle, I add it as I've seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978240).
(Note: I've also tried without the second step, I mean, with the property list out of the Settings.bundle).

3.- Edit Root.plist adding a new item with type "Child Pane" and Filename "Connection".

That's all, I think these steps should have worked, but I can't see the new property list. It's like if Root.plist doesn't recognize Connection.plist...

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i've followed a lot of tutorials and video-tutorials... nothing worked...

Thanks a lot!!
Cheers, Jorge.

Comment: more understanding flow this links https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I have found to localize your second child pane plist file in the settings bundle is to do it by hand.

I have just tested this and it works:

When you open the `Settings.bundle` in Finder, in each `language.lproj` folder, make a copy of the `Root.strings` file and rename them to `NewInfo.strings` (for example).

Once you have one this, you should see in Xcode that there are these new string files inside your settings bundle.

Now in your `NewInfo.plist` file, make sure you have a field called StringsTable and set the value of that to NewInfo (or whatever you called your new strings file).

I have just tested this in Xcode 4.2 and the localization works perfectly:

Here is a screenshot of the Root.plist where I have added a "TEST" row to open child pane. Notice the other `NewInfo.plist` and the associated strings are in the correct lang.lproj folders (again, i put them there manually in Finder).

[image]
Now here is the NewInfo.plist with the StringsTable key that corresponds to the associated .strings filename:

[image]

Here are the values of the strings files in FR and EN:

[image]

[image]

And the resulting settings page in the Simulator in both FR and EN, showing that the localization works:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I needed to change, in Connection.plist, the "Strings filename" from "Root" to "Connection".